# Complex response assertion in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm struggling a bit to build a proper test for this scenario: basically, I'm making a POST call to a web-service and trying to assert the following:

1. A 201 response is ok
2. A 409 response is also OK (but I extract this code to a variable and attempt a retry later)
3. A 400 response might be OK, but only if there is a certain string in the response body

Items 1 and 2 above I got to work fine: I handle 2 with a Response Code Extractor and an If Controller later on.

**My problem is:** how do I test for a given substring on the response body, but only in the event of a 400 response code?

The final assertion I want to build goes something like this:

"(if the response code is 201 or 409) **or** (if the response code is 400 and 'substring' found in the body) **then** OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to use [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) as it is the most flexible of all assertions provided.

Relevant Beanshell code will look as follows:

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("201") || ResponseCode.equals("409") || (ResponseCode.equals("400") && SampleResult.getResponseDataAsString().contains("something"))) {
    Failure = false;
}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more details on getting confidence by using JMeter Assertions.

Comment: Sweet, I did not know about Beanshell Assertions, and it indeed allowed me to express exactly how to validate this request. For completeness' sake, I did have to add the "else { Failure = true; } part, or this assertion would not fail the request if the conditions we're not met.